# Confirm leaving the page in an ArcGIS web app builder

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, onbeforeunload, popstate

I created an app with ESRI ArcGIS Web App Builder. Now I want to ask the user if he wants to leave the page any time he clicks the forward or back button of the browser or if he refreshes the page.

I tested a couple of solutions but none works properly.

*Solution One*

add the following in the index.html found in the root folder of the app, right after all the other js scripts imports - I add it right above the `</body>` tag

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="setLeavingConfirm.js"></script>   
</body>
```

then, inside the `setLeavingConfirm.js` I have the following:

```js
 (function setCOnfirm() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave? Changes will not be saved';
    }, {capture:true});//

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault()
      let r = confirm("Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved"); 
      if (r == true) { 
          history.back(); 
      } else { 
          history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
      }
      history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
  }, false );
})();
```

*Solution Two*

In the root folder of the app and then in `jimu.js` folder, there is the `main.js` file.

Inside that file, at the top of the `initApp()`  function  I add

```js
  on(window, 'beforeunload', function(e){        
    e.preventDefault()
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave? Changes will not be saved';
  }, {capture:true});

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault()
      let r = confirm("Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved"); 
      if (r == true) { 
          history.back(); 
      } else { 
          history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
      }
      history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
  }, false );
```

This is based on the `on` event of dojo.

As I said, both kind of work. For them to work I have to first hit Control + Shift + R on my keyboard to delete the cache. Otherwise I can leave the page without being asked first.

How can I fix either, so I get asked before leaving the page?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) and [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) events to prompt the user to confirm leaving the page should work.
But: [not all browsers handle these events in the same way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#browser_compatibility), and some (possibly Safari) may ignore the `beforeunload` event entirely if they deem it to be used for displaying a "blocking" message.

Regarding your issue with the cache, you could try adding the following code to your `setLeavingConfirm.js` file to disable caching:

```js
// Disable caching
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
});
```

That would use [jQuery's `$.ajaxSetup()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to disable caching for all AJAX requests made by the app.

And for the issue with the `beforeunload` event not being triggered consistently, you could try using a different approach to handle the back button navigation. For instance, try and use the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) instead of the `popstate` event.

```js
(function setConfirm() {
  // Disable caching
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
    });
  });

  // Add event listener for beforeunload event
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave? Changes will not be saved';
  }, {capture:true});

  // Add event listener for hashchange event
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(event) {
    let r = confirm("Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved");
    if (r == true) {
      history.back();
    } else {
      history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
  }, false);

  // Prevent hashchange event from firing on initial load
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.onhashchange = null;
    window.onhashchange = function() { /* do nothing */ };
  }, 0);
})();
```

That would add an event listener for the `hashchange` event, which is fired whenever the hash fragment of the URL changes (e.g. when the user clicks the back button). The code then displays a confirmation dialog to the user, and if the user clicks "Cancel", it prevents the page from navigating away by pushing the current URL onto the history stack.

Warning: if it works, it might work "too well", and some users may find it annoying to be prompted every time they try to leave the page. You might want to consider adding a flag to disable the confirmation dialog if the user has already saved their changes.